# How do I know current tmux session name, by running tmux command

Tags: tmux

I'm writing a script. I really want to know this. I hope tmux executable can tell me this.

I find

```
tmux rename <newname>
```

can rename current session. But I can't find a command to fetch its own name.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

With *tmux* 1.2 (and later), you can use the `-p` option of `display-message` to output a message to stdout (instead of displaying it to an attached client):

```
tmux display-message -p '#S'
```

`#S` is formatted as the session name (see the description of the `status-left` option in the man page).

Comment: +1, much better than my answer.

Comment: I really appreciate that you point out it require tmux 1.2, which is exactly the version available for openSUSE 11.3 auto online update.

Comment: With tmux 1.8, this returns the name of an attached session even when I'm not working in that session.

Comment: Tim People's answer below works with tmux 1.8 and later, as well as addresses the points he raises. That is the better answer.

Answer (score 21):

I'm surprised that, after nearly 5 years, no one has pointed out that neither of these answers is adequate. While both work fine as long as the current TTY is attached to the only tmux session on the host, these answers both fall flat if:

1. the current terminal session is not part of a tmux session, or
2. there are multiple, attached tmux sessions

In the former case, both answers here report back the name of the attached session (regardless of whether the current tty is governed by that session). In the latter case, the result is likely indeterminate or will result in multiple answers.

The proper question should be, "What is the name of the tmux session to which my current terminal session is attached?"

For he answer to *that* question, execute:

```
for s in $(tmux list-sessions -F '#{session_name}'); do
    tmux list-panes -F '#{pane_tty} #{session_name}' -t "$s"
done | grep "$(tty)" | awk '{print $2}'
```

This works regardless of the number of tmux sessions (attached or otherwise) and regardless of whether the current terminal session is or is not part of a tmux session.

Comment: Great answer. Rather than looping through each session name to list its panes, you can also use `tmux list-panes -a -F '#{pane_tty} #{session_name}'` to list every session's panes. Not sure how new `-a` is, so YMMV.

Comment: Came back to this question after using accepted answer and failing as per issues described here. Please upvote this. If possible the accepted answer should be changed.

Comment: Method 1 works fine if combined with checking `TMUX` environment variable prior to running `tmux display-message -p '#S'` for a typical desktop setup.

Comment: tmux 3.2 added `-f` filters which will let you shorted this to a single command. Not sure what version added `#{==:...}` formats that let you turn `-F` output conditional on a match to arbitrary strings, but that can be used to only output the session name for the current tty as well, but then you have to post-process to remove the blank lines.

Comment: As I am on 3.1c I use `tmux list-panes -a -F "#{?#{==:#{pane_tty},$(tty)},#{session_name},}" | grep '.'`. That's `#{?<test>,<true>,<false>}` on the outside to conditionally change the output, the test uses `#{==:<value1>,<value2>}` to test if two strings are equal, testing `#{pane_tty}` against `$(tty)` (interpolating the current tty string), and if that's true, `#{session_name}` is output, otherwise nothing.

Answer (score 9):

Extended/corrected [tim-peoples’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/410017/150988#1188041)
as per [don_crissti’s comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/328953/23408#comment578826_328953)
on [Why is this `grep -v` not functioning as expected?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/328953/23408).

"$(tty)" command in [tim-peoples’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/410017/150988#1188041)

> | grep "$(tty)" |

would not work in that context as expected. It evaluates to a string 'not a tty'.

Replacing it with a variable solves this problem.

> tty=$(tty)
>
> ...
>
> | grep "$tty" |

Also, when no tmux sessions exist, the original code would produce

*"no server running on /tmp/tmux-1000/default"* error message.

Add `2>/dev/null` and the code would run without printing out the error message.

Modified code reads as:

```
tty=$(tty)
for s in $(tmux list-sessions -F '#{session_name}' 2>/dev/null); do
    tmux list-panes -F '#{pane_tty} #{session_name}' -t "$s"
done | grep "$tty" | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: What's the improvement? If it's a necessary one you should consider submitting it as an edit rather than an answer. To make it a good answer you probably should consider including some more descriptive text.

Comment: @seth, I wanted to comment but oddly didn't have enough credit to do so.

Comment: You need [50 reputation to comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). It's usually not a good idea to comment with complex code as you lack line breaks and so on. Your edit made it a pretty good answer IMHO.

Comment: @TimPeoples While it might be a Bash issue. Bash is still the standard to code shell scripts against for compatibility on modern terminals. Sure, the posix standard is ideal; but, bash has some features all of the more advanced terminals share. By hitting Bash most of the other major terminals should just work. I just run shell check and catch a bunch of bad errors and formatting issues. (mostly using old syntax in place of current more descriptive syntax)

Answer (score 9):

- Chris Johnsen's answer returns a session name even when querying from outside of one.
- bright side's and Tim Peoples' answer assume a `tty`.

Instead, I found this to work accurately for me:

```
if [[ -n "$TMUX_PANE" ]]; then
    session_name=$(tmux list-panes -t "$TMUX_PANE" -F '#S' | head -n1)
fi
```

Comment: I don't think you need the head line since there should be only one pane with the TMUX_PANE pane id I believe?

Comment: @studgeek IIRC that is to address the first bullet point - we do not attempt to resolve `session_name` if $TMUX_PANE is not even set.

Comment: Yes, agree the TMUX_PANE check makes sense. What I'm suggesting that the `| head -n1` shouldn't be needed since only one row (or no rows) can be returned.

Comment: @studgeek list-panes prints a row for every pane in your tab (try making a split and then run the command)

Answer (score 2):

Not ideal, but you can extract the name of the attached session with `awk`:

```
tmux list-sessions -F '#{session_name} #{session_attached,yes,}' | awk '$2=="yes" {print $1}'
```

The custom format is a little easier to parse than the default.

Answer (score 0):

like @chepner 's but simpler:

```
tmux list-sessions -F "#{session_name}" -f "#{session_attached}"
```